# HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: http, permissions, unauthorized

I have an MVC project. I have created this project on my work pc.
I can build and run it there.
But when I copy and paste the project to my personal pc, 
it doesn't work anymore!

It gives 401 error. I have tried for other projects and they were running without problem. But this project gives me that error and I couldn't find a solution , I'm almost getting crazy..!

I have given all permissions to the project root folder.
There is no authentication for the porject right now.
config is like this;

```
<authentication mode="None">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/SignIn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I'm stuck, waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: Which backend technology do you use? I guess it is asp.net? Please add corresponding tag.

Comment: Yes it is an mvc project.